# R: Error in function_list[[k]](value) : could not find function "dyCandlestick"

Tags: r, trading

I am trying to plot historical forex data using R's dygraphs package - using the dyCandlestick function. 
For some reason R is not finding the dyCandlestick function, even though the dygraphs package is loaded.

I had already successfully run this code, but I added some new lines to what is shown below and now it is not working. I know that tidyverse conflicts with some functions of xts and lubridate, but I cannot understand how to go about this anyway.

```
# historical Forex data obtained from:
#https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/historical/

library(xts) # To make the convertion data-frame / xts format
library(lubridate)
library(dygraphs)
library(tidyverse)

raw_data <- read.csv("EURUSD_Candlestick_1_Hour_BID_01.01.2018-07.09.2019.csv") #data frame

i <- 1
time <- vector(length = nrow(raw_data))

for (when in raw_data$Local.time){
  dtz <- strsplit(when, " ")  #split date, time and GMT
  when <- paste(dtz[[1]][1], dtz[[1]][2]) #use only date and time
  datetime <- as.POSIXct(when, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS")
  time[i] <- strftime(datetime, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%OS")

  i<-i+1
}

#replace data with the new format
raw_data$Local.time <- NULL
raw_data$Local.time <- dmy_hms(time)
raw_data <- raw_data[c(1:77), ]

x = data.frame(raw_data$Open, raw_data$High, raw_data$Low, raw_data$Close)
#Candlestick charts use the first four data series to plot, the rest of the data series (if any) are rendered with line plotter
final_data <- xts(x = x, order.by = raw_data$Local.time)

dygraph(final_data) %>% dyCandlestick() #%>% dyOptions(sigFigs=5)
```

As soon as I run the last line, I am receiving this error message:
Error in function_list[k] : 
  could not find function "dyCandlestick"

Any help would be appreciated! Also, comments on other parts of the code which could have been done better are greatly appreciated - I'm a bit new to R :)

Comment: What happens when you [copy the code from github](https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs/blob/master/R/candlestick.R) and load the function into workspace manually?

Comment: @jay.sf I did what you suggested and now is not finding the function dyPlotter. Seems like it is not loading the whole dygraphs package, even though I uninstalled and reinstalled the package multiple times. It is giving this error:

Error in dyCandlestick(.) : could not find function "dyPlotter"
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Comment: Ok, it was something wrong with my Rstudio. Reinstalled everything and removed all the old packaged and everything is working again. @jay.sf